# Can I "trick" jQuery Draggable regarding mouse cursor movement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

A Bootstrap modal, which has been made draggable with jQuery Draggable, will move half the distance of the actual cursor movement horizontally (vertical movement is fine). This is a bug or feature and various solutions to make it follow 1:1 exist but cause other problems.

An idea I got was to "trick" jQuery Draggable so that horizontal cursor movement perceived by jQuery would be 2 x the actual one. Is there a way to do it? Something like this:

```
$('#myModal').draggable({
  drag: function( event, ui ) {
  // something here to do it?
  }
});
```

Comment: can you make a demo on  https://jsfiddle.net/ . It will be easy for us to understand your question

Answer (score 1):

In drag event you can multiply the `ui.position.left` with 2, leave `ui.position.top` as it is.
This should work

```
 $("#myModal").draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {

        // change this multiplier to go faster
        // you may have to do some flooring if you use
        // non integer values
        var mult = 2;

        var $dragme = $(event.target);

        ui.position.top = ui.position.top;
        ui.position.left = ui.position.left*mult;

        $dragme.css({
            top: ui.position.top,
            left: ui.position.left
        });
    }
});
```

here is the working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3QgJS/58/).

Comment: Thank you so much! That does precisely what I want and is better than any of the other solutions I've seen.

Comment: Unfortunately, upon further testing I noticed that it doesn't work fully. I'm trying to figure it out myself but you're more than welcome to answer, if you know. Now the modal can be dragged regardless of whether you click on it or anywhere else on the page and when clicking it sometimes even jumps to another location (I haven't figured out precisely when it does that, yet).